# Run initializer except for rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

The opposite of this question: [Run initializer only for Rake tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323632/run-initializer-only-for-rake-tasks)

Is it possible to exclude an initializer during rake tasks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap your initializer in a block like this:

```
unless ( File.basename($0) == 'rake')
   # Initializer code
end
```

Straight from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24159563/1867481